# how to allow public IP address

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have set up `eth0` to our network router with settings like:

```
  address  10.xxx.xxx.xxx    
  netmask  255.255.255.0
  broadcast 10.XXX.XXX.XX
  gateway   10.xxx.xxx.xx
```

I now need to allow a public ip address in Ubuntu. How do I do this from the terminal?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Do you have a public IP address you wish to assign to this box, or does the router have the only public IP? Do you want the public IP on the same interface, eth0?

Comment: @davidhoude - you recognize that this is an abandoned 2.5 year old question?

Comment: Absolutely not! It was on the front page, I'm guessing due to the edit. Nice catch

Answer (score 3):

If you already have an public IP address (or pool), then it is as easy as:

```
# ip addr add <ip_address>/<network_bit> dev <interface>
```

Let us say that you have an IP like 1.2.3.4, your netmask is 255.255.255.248 (gateway 1.2.3.1), and the interface is eth0, then the previous line would be:

```
# ip addr add 1.2.3.4/29 dev eth0
```

This will allow you to use this IP, but on the next reboot that configuration will no longer be there, so:

**1)** If you are not using NetworkManager:

```
# vi /etc/netwotk/interfaces
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
   address   1.2.3.4
   network   1.2.3.0
   broadcast 1.2.3.7
   netmask   255.255.255.248
   gateway   1.2.3.1
```

**2)** If you are using a graphic interface and have NetworkManager enabled (if you dont, fall back to number one)

1. Alt+F2 (execute dialog): nm-connection-editor

   - Add -> ipv4 settings -> Method: Manual
   - Add: fill in the fields
   - Add dns servers

Answer (score 2):

You can't just gin up a public IP address. You need to be allocated one by your ISP or alternatively, your regional IANA authority (RIPE, ARIN, etc.) and then advertise it via BGP.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Drt That depends - it could well be *the* answer

Comment: @Dan He is unclear about the question. It should go as a comment.

Comment: @Drt The first paragraph is a statement which could easily be the answer to the question, and good reference for anyone else here. There's nothing in the rules to say you can't request further clarification in your answer.

Comment: @Drt The downvote seems a bit unnecessary, but whatever, I have more rep than I know what to do with. Like Dan said, this could absolutely be an answer. It's all a moot point, though, as the question has been abandoned, hasn't been touched in 2.5 years. I'll delete the question part of my answer so you can remove the downvote.

Comment: @Dan - I think if everyone keeps posting questions in answer, will you be able to refer to answers quickly for solutions.

Comment: @Drt Yes - we have an `Edit` button for a reason.

Comment: @Dan You have a comment link too, you know.

Comment: @drt - You need to understand how things work here. When people post answers that contain *only* questions, that's bad and worthy of a mod flag. My answer did contain real information as well as a clarifying question. If you want to downvote all answers on the site that have clarifying questions, feel free, but I warn you, you'll likely get banned and the votes reversed.

Comment: @EEAA - no one is downvoting correct answers.

Comment: @drt - this answer *was* correct, even with the clarifying question.